# Webdriver: How to by pass SSL certificate using python

Tags: python, linux, firefox, ssl, webdriver

```
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile("C:\\Users\\xyz\\Desktop\\New folder (3)")
profile.set_preference('webdriver_assume_untrusted_issuer', True)
profile.update_preferences()
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.get("https://xx.xx.2xx.xx/login")
```

This works fine in Windows but it does not work in linux. I need to run my tests on linux.

Now I tried one way which is working but it requires usage of firefox profile. My requirement is that there are 50 devices (ip address is different and the rest is same) and framework will choose idle device.

My solution:
- create firefox profile
- download ssl certificate from my device
- add the certificate to cert8.db
- plus the above code.

But the above solution is failing sometimes. I want to avoid firefox profile if possible

Can anyone provide sample code using 'desiredcapabilities'using python?

Comment: What do you mean "_it does not work in linux_"? Of course it does not, since you are using windows-like paths instead of universal, linux ones. In Python you should always use forward slash, plus you can utilize `os.path.dirname(__file__)` and `os.path.join()` to find current path and construct new path from existing one. That should solve some of your issues (but "_does not work_" does not really say what issue you have here).

Comment: Yes, I used the below way in linux but still it didnt work             profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile(profile_directory='/users/xyz/firefox')

Comment: Umm, firefox folder located at ~/.mozilla/firefox/<profile name>. Check [this](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder_-_Firefox#Linux) page

Comment: Yes you are correct. But I installed another firefox at the specified location. I suppose the problem is not with path. I checked with wrong path/by opening a device whose ssl is already added. It is working fine. My only problem is opening a device whose ssl is not added to firefox cert8.db